# How to pass/recevice data from java/Kotlin to C++ code or vice versa in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, java-native-interface, system-services

I am working on AOSP11/12(Android) and want to communicate data from java/Kotlin to C++ code or vice versa.

Is that better way to create new service and communicate data or need to create NDK application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to have a JNI interface to communicate with native solution written in C/C++. The other way is also possible. You can as well call methods of Java class from your C/C++ applications. Primitive data types are copied as it is from Java to native calling and arbitrary data types (objects) are passed as pass by reference mechanism.

This would be a good read to start with:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

While designing an application, please ensure the following:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have developed test JNI application its java and C++ code in same project. In real time java code in android app and C++ code in some where else in AOSP source code.How to communicate in that scenario. Can you please suggest me